# How to solve Forbidden numerice value: Infinity issue when converting JsonObject?

Tags: android, json

I am an Android app developer. I found a problem while converting a string created in json format through `JSONObject`.

```
var str = "{" +
    "success=true, " +
    "info={ " +
    "_id=60612354050e050647329552," +
    "name=Hello" +
    "}" +
    "}"

try {
    val obj = JSONObject(str)
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST result $obj")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST Error() $e")
}
```

`_id` is a combination of letters and numbers, randomly generated by the computer. However, if `_id` consisting of numbers and the letter e is entered as above, the following error occurs.

> TEST Error() org.json.JSONException: Forbidden numeric value: Infinity

t seems that the alphabet e is recognized as an exponent, and the number is too large, so it is recognized as infinity. `_id` will continue to be created as a combination of numbers and letters, so is there a way to read `_id` as characters while converting it into JSONObject?

Comment: I wrote the json code wrong. The question has been edited.

Comment: It is a bit better now, but still not correct. But the real problem is that `_id` should be a string and not a number (i.e. the value must be quoted).